# Angular UI Router: decide child state template on the basis of parent resolved object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

this is my app.js file-
i have one parent state and two child states.
Both the child views need the object.

```
    states.push({
      name: 'parentstate',
      url: '/parent/:objId',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'views/parentview.html',
      controller: function() {},
      resolve: {
        obj: function(OBJ, $stateParams) {
          return OBJ.get($stateParams.objId);
        }
      }
    });
```

i want to use this resolved obj to decide child template

```
    states.push({
      name: 'parentstate.childs',
      url: '/edit',
      views: {
        "view1@parentstate": {
          templateUrl: 'views/view1',
          controller: 'view1Ctrl'
        },
        "view2@parentstate": {
          templateUrl: function(obj) {
            if (obj.something == something) {
              return "views/view2first.html";
           } else {
              return 'views/view2second.html';
            }
          },
          controller: 'view2Ctrl'
        }
      }  
    });
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a working [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/rSpo2dzJfJU23rzREasd?p=preview). Instead of `templateUrl` we should use the `templateProvider`. This is new state def:

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('parentstate.childs', {
      url: '/edit',
      views: {
        "view1@parentstate": {
          templateUrl: 'views.view1.html',
          controller: 'view1Ctrl',
        },
        "view2@parentstate": {
          templateProvider: function($http, $stateParams, OBJ) {

            var obj = OBJ.get($stateParams.objId);
            var templateName = obj.id == 1
              ? "views.view2.html"
              : "views.view2.second.html"
              ;
        
            return $http
                  .get(templateName)
                  .then(function(tpl){
                    return tpl.data;
                  });
          },
          controller: 'view2Ctrl',
        }
      }
    });
```

Why are we using this approach? as documented here:

#### [Templates](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#templates)

> **TemplateUrl**
> ... `templateUrl` can also be a function that returns a url. **It takes one preset parameter, `stateParams`, which is NOT injected.**
>
> **TemplateProvider**
> Or you can use a **template provider** function which **can be injected, has access to locals**, and must return template HTML, like this:

Check the `TemplateProvider` based solution in this working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rSpo2dzJfJU23rzREasd?p=preview)

Comment: But i want to use that obj in view1Ctrl too. And i dont want to make two api calls.

Comment: I showed you, how powerful `ui-router` is. Also, I tried to explain to you how the Templating is designed, and what we can achieve with `TemplateUrl` and what with `TemplateProvider`. Now its up to you how to solve the reuse of the *boj*. I would vote for caching... but that is not the `ui-router` responsibility... BTW In my experience, I never needed to drive template selection by some params. Just drive the state and its template... inside of the template use `directives` to render the content based on the content... Does it help?

Comment: yeah it definitely helps. As you said you never needed to decide template on basis of some params. I think my approach is wrong and i should think again. I will see how i can use directives for this case. Thank you.

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow. I am using ui-router and cannot imagine world without that. Just our thinking must be a bit chnaged ;) You will be able to upvote, once you get reputation 15 (or more)... but you can accept! if the asnwer helps and get some score as well ;) good luck with `ui-router`