# Angular UI-router and using dynamic templates

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to load a template file using a rootscope value as for it's name.
I have a init controller which sets the $rootScope.template to "whatever.html", then I have my route like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('/', {
  url: '/',
  access: 'public',
  views: {
    page: {
      controller: 'HomeCtrl',
      templateProvider: function($templateFactory, $rootScope) {
        return $templateFactory.fromUrl('/templates/' + $rootScope.template);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

But this doesn't work. It actually freezes the whole chrome so that I have to kill the process in order to stop it... I've also tried this with templateUrl but with no results.

So how could I use my dynamic template file with UI-router?

Comment: could you create a plunkr.co to show this failing in context?

Comment: templateProviders seems okay. I created a plunker for this: http://plnkr.co/edit/x8tsIBkKHM1cxfstyESt?p=preview
So, problem is probably not here.

Comment: Yes, seems to work ok. My problem was/is that this $rootscope value is a query value from a database. Now everything works ok if I declare the $rootScope.template manually but the query takes too long (or I don't really know what the problem is) and is therefore not ready by the time templateProvider would need it.

Comment: Any ideas how to fetch my template name and use that in my router? Like the question above but instead of $rootScope.template = "whatever.html" it would be a query value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similiar to your other question *(in order I found them)*: [Angular and UI-Router, how to set a dynamic templateUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26868796/1679310), I also created [a working plunker to show how to](http://plnkr.co/edit/WYdNldBM0HiureFGgBqJ?p=preview). How it would work?

So, if this would be state call:

```
<a href="#/parent/child/1">#/parent/child/1</a>
<a href="#/parent/child/2">#/parent/child/2</a>
```

And these would be states:

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('parent', {
      url: '/parent',
      //abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'views.parentview.html',
      controller: function($scope) {},
    });

  $stateProvider
    .state('parent.child', {
      url: '/child/:someSwitch',
      views: {
         // see more below
```

Then we can use this `templateProvider` definiton:

```
templateProvider: function($http, $stateParams, GetName) {

    // async service to get template name from DB
    return GetName
        .get($stateParams.someSwitch)
        // now we have a name
        .then(function(obj){
           return $http
              // let's ask for a template
              .get(obj.templateName)
              .then(function(tpl){
                  // haleluja... return template
                  return tpl.data;
           });      
        })

},
```

What we can see is chaining of async results:

```
// first return of promise
return asyncstuff
  .then(function(x){
    // second return of a promise once done first
    return asyncstuff
      .then(function(y){  
       // again  
        return asyncstuff
          .then(function(z){
            return ... it
          }
      }

  }
```

And that's what the magical `templateProvider` can do for us... wait until all promises are resolved and continue execution with known template name and even its content. Check the example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/WYdNldBM0HiureFGgBqJ?p=preview). More about template provider: [Angular UI Router: decide child state template on the basis of parent resolved object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25289135/1679310)

Comment: This looks promising, but I gotta ask, is the $http service really necessary to get a template? (This is what I understood from looking at your plunker example), the factory GetName#get does return the template name already, so... is the $http call on line 29 of your plunker necessary for all this to work? and why? Thanks!

Comment: @Jose in case I do understand your question, I would rather use $templateRequest discussed e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28872022/1679310) or [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30409867/1679310)

Comment: Cool, looking at your suggestion now. However, for argument's sake, do you think you could answer my question? Does templateProvider indeed requires a *final* call to $http to get a template? Thank you for your kind reply.

Comment: @Jose, sorry do not have so much time.. but I guess yes. GetName just gets the name, while $http get the content of it. templateProvider must return the template! so, it must call $http to get it. Hope it helps a bit.. maybe issue fresh question, and large audience could give you even better direction..

Comment: That's ok! this was good enough for now. We programmers are always busy! your suggestion looks even better. Reading up! Have a nice day.