# How to change only one ui-view out of many. Without changing state

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my HTML I have three columns where I am rendering 3 different HTML templates.

```
 <div id="col1" ui-view="col1"></div>
 <div id="col2" ui-view="col2"></div>
 <div id="col3" ui-view="col3"></div>
```

State demo which will render all this is like following.

```
$stateProvider
  .state('demo',{
    views: {
      'col1': {
        templateUrl: 'FirstTemplate.html'
      },
      'col2': {
        templateUrl: 'SecondTemplate.html'
      },
      'col3': {
        templateUrl: 'ThirdTemplate.html'
      }
    }
  })
```

My question is, how can I change `templateurl` of `col3` from `ThirdTemplate.html` to `NewTemplate.html`, without changing the state.

Comment: check this link: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router

Comment: I just did and unfortunately I still don't know how to do it. Would you kindly point it out for me?

Comment: @Ved I am new to this but as I looked at their example, I think they are changing their states using `ui-sref`. What I want to do is something different, I want to stay in the same state and just change view(templateURL) dynamically.

Comment: is it ok for you to use ng-show and ng-hide to just change the view..

Comment: @Ved That is one way, but by doing that I will be loading all my templates at a time when the state is activated and I am going to have a LOT of these templates, That is the reason I am looking for a way to change them dynamically.

Comment: yes.. you are right.. let me see.. how to achieve this..

Comment: the link i posted is fine. It will work for you.. check this example.http://embed.plnkr.co/M03tYgtfqNH09U4x5pHC/preview

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/M03tYgtfqNH09U4x5pHC?p=preview

Comment: @Ved You have created nested states in there, and still changing from state to state to change views.

Comment: It's the same thing man, different states.

Comment: I found this on google. I haven't created it..

Comment: I think, If you wanna change the views without routes don't use views use ng-include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this:

> My question is, how can I change templateurl of *col3* from `ThirdTemplate.html` to `NewTemplate.html`, **without changing the state.** ?

It is not possible. It is not intended nor supported.

The idea behind the UI-Router is navigation among states *(even without using url, `$state.go()`)*. Once the state **TO** is found/resolved, all its setting are converted into implementations *(`controllerProvider` returning controller or string which is used to find controller, `templateProvider` returning template, etc.)*

After that, state is stable and solid. We can use some other angular features *(directives)* to manipulate the DOM, but unless we will `change the state` - its parts are fixed.

In case, we can accept state change (including current state reload) we can profit e.g. from Template Provider:

- [Trying to Dynamically set a templateUrl in controller based on constant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27774287/1679310)
- [Angular and UI-Router, how to set a dynamic templateUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26868796/1679310)

*NOTE: state change above means: 1) navigate to other or 2) reload current.*

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-include="'NewTemplate.html'"></div>

<div ng-hide="'NewTemplate.html'">Thirdtemplate.html</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Naresh, thanks for your answer, but could you please add a few words of explanation? A code-only answer isn't always self explanatory :)

Comment: In Thirdtemplate.html page  include a new html(NewTemplate.html) using ng-include directive  based on conditions you can hide the view of previous html i.e in templateUrl (Thirdtemplate.html)

Comment: @Nersh - great, almost there ;) Just edit your answer to add to it what you wrote in the comment!