# Why im getting 404 error when i using .html for state?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have this states: first one in partial view and second one is html page and they are in folder View/Account.First one is working but secondone is not.It say 404 page could not be found. How can i configure state for .html page.Any suggestion?

```
.state('account.payoutconfirmation', {
    url: '/ticketprint',
    templateUrl:
        function (stateParams) {
            return mainTemplateService.getTemplateUrl(stateParams, '/account/payoutconfirmation');
        }
}).state('account.state', {
    url: '/printticket',
    templateUrl:
        function (stateParams) {
            return mainTemplateService.getTemplateUrl(stateParams, "/account/state.html")
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say, there could be some *typo*. Anyhow, in case we are using some **`mainTemplateService`** to load the *url*, we should not use *`templateUrl`*, but `templateProvider`.

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wWtVYEUVgYldDkhLLch8?p=preview)

This could be the service:

```
  .factory('mainTemplateService', ['$templateRequest', function($templateRequest) {
    return {
      getTemplateUrl: function(stateParams, urlPart) {
        var url = "temp" + urlPart; 
        return $templateRequest(url); 
      }
    }
  }])
```

And these are states:

```
.state('account.payoutconfirmation', {
  url: '/ticketprint',
  templateProvider: ['$stateParams', 'mainTemplateService',
    function(stateParams, mainTemplateService) {
      return mainTemplateService.getTemplateUrl(stateParams, '/account/payoutconfirmation');
  }],
})
.state('account.state', {
  url: '/printticket',
  templateProvider: ['$stateParams', 'mainTemplateService',
    function(stateParams, mainTemplateService) {
      return mainTemplateService.getTemplateUrl(stateParams, "/account/state.html")
  }],
})
```

Check [it here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wWtVYEUVgYldDkhLLch8?p=preview)

Also, check these:

- [Angular and UI-Router, how to set a dynamic templateUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26868796/1679310)
- [Trying to Dynamically set a templateUrl in controller based on constant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27774287/1679310)