# Trying to Dynamically set a templateUrl in controller based on constant

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to change the templateUrl associated with controller based on a preset constant that I've defined in my angularjs bootstrap.  I can't figure out how to change that. I've experimented with UrlRouteProvider but have not been able to figure out how to pull the html in from the file system with that.  I'm stuck on templateUrl.

In the below code, the output first shows that "svcc is indeed passed into the first function's console.out but in the templateUrl definition function, CONFIG is undefined.

I'm open to other ways to do this.

```
    var app = angular.module('svccApp', [
        'ui.router'
    ]);

    var myConstant = {};
    myConstant.codeCampType = "svcc";
    app.constant("CONFIG", myConstant);

    app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider','CONFIG',
        function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,CONFIG) {
            console.log(CONFIG.codeCampType);
            $stateProvider
                .state('home', {
                    url: '/home',
                    //templateUrl: 'index5templateA.html',   (THIS WORKS)
                    templateUrl: function(CONFIG) {
                        console.log('in templateUrl ' + CONFIG.codeCampType);
                        if (CONFIG.codeCampType === "svcc") {
                            return 'index5templateA.html';
                        } else {
                            return 'index5templateB.html';
                        }
                    },
                    controller: function ($state) {
                    }
                });
        }]);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I created a [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jzfF34rm4vCbq4mijiHN?p=preview)
You are almost there, just the syntax is **`'templateProvider'`**:

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    //templateUrl: 'index5templateA.html',   (THIS WORKS)
    // templateUrl: function(CONFIG) {
    templateProvider: function(CONFIG) {
    ...
```

Snippet from doc:

#### [Templates](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#templates)

> **TemplateUrl**
> ... `templateUrl` can also be a function that returns a url. **It takes one preset parameter, `stateParams`, which is NOT injected.**
>
> **TemplateProvider**
> Or you can use a **template provider** function which **can be injected, has access to locals**, and must return template HTML, like this:

So in our case, that would be the implementation:

```
 $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        //templateUrl: 'index5templateA.html',   (THIS WORKS)
        templateProvider: function(CONFIG, $http, $templateCache) {
            console.log('in templateUrl ' + CONFIG.codeCampType);
            
            var templateName = 'index5templateB.html';
            
            if (CONFIG.codeCampType === "svcc") {
                 templateName = 'index5templateA.html';
            } 
            var tpl = $templateCache.get(templateName);
            
            if(tpl){
              return tpl;
            }
            
            return $http
               .get(templateName)
               .then(function(response){
                  tpl = response.data
                  $templateCache.put(templateName, tpl);
                  return tpl;
              });
        },
        controller: function ($state) {
        }
    });
```

Check the [examle here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jzfF34rm4vCbq4mijiHN?p=preview)

Also check:

- [Angular UI Router: decide child state template on the basis of parent resolved object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25289135/1679310)
- [Angular and UI-Router, how to set a dynamic templateUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26868796/1679310)

Comment: Thanks Radim.  I did see both of those posts but I feel like I'm not so close.  Getting the templates with $http and caching them really confuses me.  I think I'm almost there if I would return a template and not templateUrl.  I feel like if $templateFactory.fromUrl worked I'd be there but that provider seems to no longer exist.

Comment: In so much hurry... sorry... I created the plunker, and that should show how to handle caching and $http and... please check the latest link ... please

Comment: Thanks Radim.  Is the function necessary that you set $rootScope in?  Your solution is elegant.  Thanks so much, what I was hoping for.

Comment: No no ;) ;) I usually do have some start up scritps in my toolbelt... to create plunker ASAP. ;) that's just... Enjoy mighty UI-Router

Answer (score 3):

I have to add another answer, related to brand new feature of angular 1.3

[$templateRequest](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateRequest)

> The `$templateRequest` service downloads the provided template using `$http` and, upon success, stores the contents inside of `$templateCache`.

**Usage**

```
$templateRequest(tpl, [ignoreRequestError]);
```

**Arguments**
- tpl   string  - *The HTTP request template URL*

- ignoreRequestError (optional) boolean - *Whether or not to ignore the exception when the request fails or the template is empty*

And [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BFCQ2MQ9HiCmFJ4gpD6v?p=preview)

```
templateProvider: function(CONFIG, $templateRequest) {
    console.log('in templateUrl ' + CONFIG.codeCampType);

    var templateName = 'index5templateB.html';

    if (CONFIG.codeCampType === "svcc") {
         templateName = 'index5templateA.html';
    } 

    return $templateRequest(templateName);
},
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 var app = angular.module('svccApp', [
        'ui.router'
    ]);

    var myConstant = {};
    myConstant.codeCampType = "svcc";

    app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider','CONFIG',
        function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,CONFIG) {
            console.log(CONFIG.codeCampType);
            $stateProvider
                .state('home', {
                    url: '/home',
                    //templateUrl: 'index5templateA.html',   (THIS WORKS)
                    templateUrl: function() {
                        if (myConstant.codeCampType === "svcc") {
                            return 'index5templateA.html';
                        } else {
                            return 'index5templateB.html';
                        }
                    },
                    controller: function ($state) {
                    }
                });
        }]);
```

Comment: when I test this, I don't appear to have access to myConstant in the function

Comment: you will. app.config will have closure of myConstant. You are creating your myConstant as global variable. When your templateUrl function will execute you will have your myConstant.

Comment: You are clearly right when i run it but i'm confused.  In my example it seems not to be global but in your example it does.  What I not understanding?  -thanks

Comment: please ignore my last comment. I get it now.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862193/javascript-global-variables