# Angular pass parameters in templateurl in stateprovider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using a `$stateprovider` as follows from **angular-ui-router** in my angular application:

```
.state('order', {
        url: "/order/:id",
        templateUrl: "/myapp/order"
    })
```

In the above scenario, we are passing an `id` to the controller and we can call it as `ui-sref="order({id: 1234})"`.

But now i want to make a direct call to the backend by not using a controller and pass the above as follows:

```
.state('order', {
        url: "/order",
        templateUrl: "/myapp/order/:id"
    })
```

But obviously my syntax is wrong here.
How do i achieve this scenario?

Comment: Perhaps take a look at templateProvider? I'm not sure what you mean by direct call to the backend.

Comment: i have django on the backend that renders the partial template based on the url i am calling. The template is rendered if i make a call directly to the url. This url has a django view that renders the template. So i am trying to call this url in the stateprovider directly without using the controller

Comment: Isn't templateProvider the way to go then, since you have access to the $stateParams, and you do a http request of your template with the id?

Comment: can you help me with that? i am trying something like this: .state('order', {
     url: "/irms/order/:id",
     templateProvider: function ($http, orderService, $stateParams) {

          return orderService.getUrl($stateParams.id).then(function(url) {
            return $http.get(url);
          })
        }
    })

Comment: Try? 

    templateProvider: function($timeout, $stateParams, $http) {
              var url = '/myapp/order/' + $stateParams.id;

              return $timeout(function () {
              return $http.get(url).then(function(html){
                  return html.data;
              })}, 100);

          }]

Comment: hi this worked great.... but it is not displaying the html though... When i checked the preview in the network, it shows the partial view correctly but it is not displaying it in the ui-view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I [created working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/gDJlMDCIcPaYtUcwJ8S9?p=preview). It is adjsuting thiw Q & A:

#### [Trying to Dynamically set a templateUrl in controller based on constant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27774287/1679310)

Let's have templates `template-A.html` and `template-B.html` in our example. 
The state def with **`templateProvider`** would look like this

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('order', {
      url: '/order/:id',

      templateProvider: function($http, $templateCache, $stateParams) {

        var id = $stateParams.id || 'A';
        var templateName = 'template-' + id + '.html';

        var tpl = $templateCache.get(templateName);

        if (tpl) {
          return tpl;
        }

        return $http
          .get(templateName)
          .then(function(response) {
            tpl = response.data
            $templateCache.put(templateName, tpl);
            return tpl;
          });
      },
      controller: function($state) {}
    });
```

And now we can call it like this

```
  <a href="#/order/A">
  <a href="#/order/B">
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/gDJlMDCIcPaYtUcwJ8S9?p=preview)

And what's more, with latest version of angularjs we can even make it super simple:

**[$templateRequest](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateRequest)**

Updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/llXwUqpYKzoS2YuXKZCL?p=preview)

```
.state('order', {
  url: '/order/:id',

  templateProvider: function($templateRequest, $stateParams) {

    var id = $stateParams.id || 'A';
    var templateName = 'template-' + id + '.html';
    return $templateRequest(templateName);
  },
  controller: function($state) {}
});
```