# How can I route to different URLS in angularjs UI-Router for items in ng-repeat, Need to modify state in ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I am using UI-Router and my html looks something below:

```
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat = "guy in  guys">
      <a ui-sref="person">{{guy}}{{$index+1}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

The output is below:

Hello Plunker!

File1
File2
File3

and my angular code is something like below:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.val = "This is my Message..."
  $scope.guys = ['File1','File2','File3']
});

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('person{something needs to be here}', {
        url: "/route1",
        templateUrl: "file1.html"
    })
    .state('person{something needs to be here}', {
        url: "/route2",
        templateUrl: "file2.html"
    })    
})
```

Can someone help with with what needs to be populated here, My goal is that clicking File1 should open file.html and clicking file2 should open file2.html

In short my question is how do I open different files/templates/partials when clicking on items that are repeated in an ng-repeat directive and how to specify url parameters in state of `UI-Router`

thanks much

http://plnkr.co/edit/p6Qlzh7XjjeXUJ5I8Z8h?p=preview

Comment: If you'd like to observe similar issue and solution... http://stackoverflow.com/q/30288859/1679310

Comment: @RadimKöhler Can you please help here, I created a demo issue at 
http://plnkr.co/edit/p6Qlzh7XjjeXUJ5I8Z8h?p=preview

Comment: Of course, give me few minutes

Comment: @RadimKöhler: thanks a ton buddy, I think I solved  this  problem but I am not sure if thats the approach approach. updated
http://plnkr.co/edit/p6Qlzh7XjjeXUJ5I8Z8h?p=preview

Comment: I tried to express that all in answer with updated and working plunker.. hope it helps

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/72e1N3BU7rOB2sI7pTaQ?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an [updated plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/nFRqLjcLS24J33XxztLm?p=preview)

State would be looking like this:

```
.state('guy_route2', {
    url: "/route/{index:int}",
    templateProvider: function($templateRequest, $stateParams) {

      var index = $stateParams.index + 1;
      var templateName = 'file' + index + '.html';

      return $templateRequest(templateName);
    },
})
```

this would be the body:

```
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">  

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat = "guy in guys">
      <a ui-sref="guy_route2({index: $index})">{{guy}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>


 <h3>Target for state</h3>

 <div ui-view=""></div>
</body>
```

See the  **`<div ui-view=""></div>`**, essential target for our states. And the ui-sref:

```
 ui-sref="guy_route2({index: $index})"
```

where we pass the state name `'guy_route2'`, and the function call contains object representing the state params `({index: $index})`

Check that all [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/nFRqLjcLS24J33XxztLm?p=preview)

The templateProvider "magic" details could be found here:

- [Angular pass paramters in templateurl in stateprovider](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28866053/1679310)
- [Trying to Dynamically set a templateUrl in controller based on constant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27774287/1679310)

EXTEND:

With a radio I would adjust it [like this](http://plnkr.co/edit/QvSS0hd3r9DKfexWY3O3?p=preview)

```
  <h3>radio</h3>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="guy in guys">
      <input type="radio" 
      value="{{$index}}"
      ng-model="Model.selected" 
      ng-change="go(Model.selected)" 
      id="something{{$index}}"
      /><label for="something{{$index}}">{{guy}}</label>
    </li>

  </ul>
```

And the go function

```
$scope.Model = { selected: null }; 
$scope.go = function(index){ 
    $state.go('guy_route2', {index: index}) ;}
});
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/QvSS0hd3r9DKfexWY3O3?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks dude, I have something nonsense to add here, I want to add ui-sref to radio button and not a link, though it works but radios wont get checked
replace anchors with

 <input type="radio" ui-sref="guy_route2({index: $index})" name="something" />{{guy}}

http://plnkr.co/edit/XorIs2griMOJB5Wjy6Gg?p=preview

Comment: Hope now you should have the answers ;) Good luck with UI-Router

Comment: but why do all the 3 radios get selected?

Comment: Yeah, just wanted to ship a version ASAP to you... here is updated one http://plnkr.co/edit/QvSS0hd3r9DKfexWY3O3?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Buddy, +1 added and accepted. what did you do to fix radios getting selected, all 3 initially

Comment: My actual problem was this. I think there is something called resolve in UI-router. Can you please help here. I need to update the same view using a controller. I put up a plunk for your reference. Thanks a Million for your help
http://plnkr.co/edit/sxvtPiABbnHnkDjVbDE6?p=preview

Comment: Tried to do my best to guess what you wanted.. check my answer.. hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Use only one route with a parameter:

```
.state("person", {
    url: "/person/:file",
    ....
});
```

Then in the template controller get the file parameter with $stateParams, load the html content with $http and put the result in a ng-bind-html tag attribute.

Comment: I think you asking me same question?

Comment: Then in the template controller get the file parameter with $stateParams, load the html content with $http and put the result in a ng-bind-html tag attribute.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in [comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/911022/mike), we can use even **`resolve`**.

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5TpRtG4yySnC5RP1LKUi?p=preview)

This could be the `data.json`

```
[
    {
    "id":1,
    "name":"Someone 1"
    },
    {
    "id":2,
    "name":"Someone 2"
    },
    {
    "id":3,
    "name":"Someone 3"
    }
]
```

And these state def would use that file to produce list and a detail. Parent state with resolve

```
  .state('guys', {
    url: "/route",
    templateUrl:'guys.html',
    controller:'listCtrl',
    resolve: { 
      guys: ['$http', function($http){
        return $http
            .get("data.json")
            .then(function(response){
              return response.data; 
            })
      }],
    }
  })
```

And child with the templating driven by passed id:

```
  .state('guy', {
    parent: 'guys',
    url: "/:id",
    controller:'MyCtrl',
    templateProvider: function($templateRequest, $stateParams) {

      var index = $stateParams.id;
      var templateName = 'file' + index + '.html';

      return $templateRequest(templateName);
    },
  })
```

And that should show how to use UI-Router with resolve

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/5TpRtG4yySnC5RP1LKUi?p=preview)

See also

- [AngularJS - UI Router - Unable to use resolve to provide my controller with data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29684417/1679310)
- [Angularjs ui-router abstract state with resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27168835/1679310)
- [UI-Router will not resolve $http call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30410384/1679310)

Comment: Thanks a milllion  buddy but I just want a simple partial to load the data using controller, I dont want to have file1, file2, file3 partails. Single partial is supposed to contain the data for all the three routes.

Comment: There is another plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/tnqjJFn9rGwmrzA0a6u8?p=preview -  Maybe, I did too much.. ;) to reduce that child state features was not an issue.. (it was more a bonus ;) So, do you have your answer? is this **`resolve : {}`** stuff workgin for you? *Simply not sure about your comment...*

Comment: Thanks dude, it is really helpful but in 
$scope.guy = $scope.guys[$stateParams.id];

what is guy? Is it state or data of ng-repeat?

Comment: Sorry, Mike, have to stop here. I am not consultant for free for sure ;) And while only measure if answer is helpful here is up-voting and accepting, the only/last thing I can add here: **glad if I helped** For more details, please issue new question. You will get more attention from larger audience. If you'd not be getting the answer - and think I can help ;) - let me know, share a link... I do like to assist, but with some results... ;) good luck, sir