# AngularJs dynamic template display with same route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to Angular Js. Recently I was doing work with routes and templateUrl. This was straight forward. But now I want to do something if that is even possible.

I want to show different view or template with same route but depending on the attribute of the data that I get from the Server. If the status is  A then show the edit-mode and if the status is B then show the read-only mode. The data values are same except the status. I was doing ng-if in the template and toggle back and forth. It could be done this way but for the re-usability purpose I want to have a separate templates for each and call the template in the route depending on those attributes.

Let me know if that can be done. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/9d0jXEUOG9PlIhkYwwvA?p=preview), which is close to this Q & A: [Trying to Dynamically set a templateUrl in controller based on constant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28872022/1679310)

In case I understand you properly, the way could be:

- use `$stateParams` for switching *read* / *edit*
- `templateProvider` to select template
- `$templateRequest` to profit from angular native wrapper over `$http` + `$tempalteCache`

The state def would be very simple:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('myState', {
        url: '/myState/:operation',

        templateProvider: ['$stateParams', '$templateRequest',
          function($stateParams, $templateRequest) {

            var templateName = 'read.html';

            if ($stateParams.operation === "edit") {
                 templateName = 'edit.html';
            } 

            return $templateRequest(templateName);
        }],
        controller: function ($state) {
        }
    });
```

And links to this state:

```
  <a href="#/myState/read">
  <a href="#/myState/edit">
```

Check the examle in [action here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9d0jXEUOG9PlIhkYwwvA?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort!. I got the idea.