# Angular ui.router reload parent templateProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an abstract base template that loads the navigation based on the user type.  This part works on initial loading.  The problem is I can't get the parent templateProvider to reload when the user has logged in or out afterwards. I have tried the solutions [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/582) to reload the parent template, but the nav templates aren't affected. Is there a way to reload the templateProvider, or a better way of doing this? Ideally I won't have to add the nav provider to every child route.

The routes:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('base', {
            abstract: true,
            views: {
                content: {
                    template: '<ui-view></ui-view>',
                },
                nav: {
                    templateProvider: function ($templateFactory, User, $stateParams){
                        if(User.exists()){
                            var url = '/static/html/navs/' + User.get.type + '.html';
                            return $templateFactory.fromUrl(url);
                        }
                        else{
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })

        .state('base.index', {
            url: '/',
            controller: 'loginController',
            templateUrl: 'static/html/landing/login.html'
        })
```

Controller function with attempts from [github issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/582):

```
scope.login_submit = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    User.login(scope.login, function(res){
         $state.transitionTo(
             'base.dashboard', null, 
             {reload: true, inherit: true, notify: true }
         );
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created [working example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7Tyha6hzUXulGZ7I4vNt?p=preview). It is coming from this [Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28872022/1679310)

This would be the adjusted state def:

```
.state('base', { 
    abstract: true,
    views: {
        '': {
            template: '<ui-view></ui-view>',
        },
        /*
        nav: {
            templateProvider: function ($templateFactory, User, $stateParams){
                if(User.exists()){
                    var url = '/static/html/navs/' + User.get.type + '.html';
                    return $templateFactory.fromUrl(url);
                }
                else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        },*/
        nav: {
          templateProvider: ['User', '$templateRequest', function(User, templateRequest){ 

            var tplName = 'templates/templateNotExists.html';

            if(User.exists) {

              tplName = 'templates/templateExists.html';
            }

            return templateRequest(tplName); 
          }],
        },
    }
})
```

As we can see, we use *new* feature called  **`'$templateRequest'`**, to get html template from server, based on the url.

and these are controllers and services

```
.controller('loginController', ['$scope', 'User', function ($scope, User) {
  $scope.User = User;
}])
.factory('User', function(){   return { exists: false, }; })
```

And this is the content of the template of the child 'base.index' state:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="User.exists" />
<button ng-click="$state.go('base.index', null, {reload: true})" >reload</button>
```

Check that all in [action here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7Tyha6hzUXulGZ7I4vNt?p=preview)