# Angular UI-Router dynamic routing based on slug from API Ajax Call. Load view based on slug

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Examples slugs in server database accessible through API:

```
{slug: "john-smith",type: "user"}
{slug: "microsoft-technologies",type: "company"}
```

**scenario 1 :** user view & controller : http://localhost/john-smith

```
.state('user', {
    url: '/:user',
    templateUrl: 'partial-user.html',
    controller: 'userCtrl'
})
```

**scenario 2 :** company view & controller : http://localhost/microsoft-technologies

```
.state('company', {
    url: '/:company',
    templateUrl: 'partial-company.html',
    controller: 'companyCtrl'
})
```

Now I want to make make a dynamic state based the slug getting from API Call to the server.

I written a **imaginary code.** But I'm not getting way to achieve

```
// Example URL http://localhost/john-smith
.state('hybrid', {
    // /john-smith
    url: '/:slug',
    templateUrl: function () {
        return "partial-"+type+".html"
    },
    controllerProvider: function (rt) {
        return type+'Controller'
    },
    resolove: {
        type: function ($http, $stateParams) {
            $http.get({
                method: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost/api/" + $stateParams.slug
            }).success(function(response, status, headers, config){
                //response = {slug: "john-smith",type: "user"}
                return response.type
            })
            return 
        }
    }    
})
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NPV9W1XtySg80rcBLCSG?p=preview).

It comes from similar issue: [AngularJS ui-router - two identical route groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30288859/1679310)

In case, I do understand your aim properly, this would be the adjusted state definition *(I just skipped the $http and server response part, just working with passed parameter)*:

```
.state('hybrid', {
    // /john-smith
    url: '/{slug:(?:john|user|company)}',
    templateProvider: ['type', '$templateRequest',
      function(type, templateRequest) 
      {
        var tplName = "tpl.partial-" + type + ".html";
        return templateRequest(tplName);
      }
    ],
    controllerProvider: ['type',
      function(type) 
      {
        return type + 'Controller';
      }
    ],
    resolve: {
      type: ['$http', '$stateParams',
        function($http, $stateParams) {
          /*$http.get({
            method: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost/api/" + $stateParams.slug
        }).success(function(response, status, headers, config){
            //response = {slug: "john-smith",type: "user"}
            return response.type
        })*/
          return $stateParams.slug
        }
      ]
    }
})
```

One change is the *`resolove : {}`* became: **`resolve : {}`**. Another is fixture of the controller def (rt vs type). And also, we do profit from built in features `templateProvider` and `$templateRequest` *(similar here: [Angular ui.router reload parent templateProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29785692/1679310))*

check that in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NPV9W1XtySg80rcBLCSG?p=preview)

EXTEND, including the $http part ([extended plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/P6cspZI53I8Qdb7fDBT9?p=preview))

Let's adjust (for plunker purposes) the server part to return this info as **`data.json`**:

```
{
 "john-smith": {"type": "user"},
 "lady-ann": {"type": "user"},
 "microsoft-technologies" : {"type": "company" },
 "big-company" : {"type": "company" },
 "default": {"type" : "other" }
}
```

And these links:

```
<a href="#/john-smith">
<a href="#/lady-ann">

<a href="#/microsoft-technologies">
<a href="#/big-company">

<a href="#/other-unknown">
```

Will be easily managed by this adjusted state def:

```
  .state('hybrid', {
    // /john-smith
    url: '/:slug',
    templateProvider: ['type', '$templateRequest',
      function(type, templateRequest) 
      {
        var tplName = "tpl.partial-" + type + ".html";
        return templateRequest(tplName);
      }
    ],
    controllerProvider: ['type',
      function(type) 
      {
        return type + 'Controller';
      }
    ],
    resolve: {
      type: ['$http', '$stateParams',
        function($http, $stateParams) {
          return $http.get("data.json")
            .then(function(response){
              var theType = response.data[$stateParams.slug]
                  ||response.data["default"]
              return theType.type
            })
        }
      ]
    }
  })
```

Check [that updated stuff here](http://plnkr.co/edit/P6cspZI53I8Qdb7fDBT9?p=preview)

Comment: I want `return type` based on http response& http request based on `$stateParams.slug`. From http response i can get template/controller name

Comment: This is just a consumption of the $http result... which I skipped,(because not having the server part in the plunker)... But that is easy bit. I did the rest for you.. controllers, templates... you will just call server, recieve response and pass it instead of my type result.. as object

Comment: but how to pass promise from http is my doubt. Please use setTimeout instead of $http. see here http://plnkr.co/edit/UngzlI2g9DSHVM2CKfwC?p=preview [Plnkr]

Comment: I extended example and make it working with $http (a bit simplified then real server, but...working ;) Hope this will give you all the answers.. Enjoy UI-Router

Comment: Do you have the same solution but for a most recent version of angular ?