# Is it possible to load a template via AJAX request for UI-Router in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state, angular-template

I know this might [get an answer here](http://bl.ocks.org/marcoslin/b59cfa9a9a44bde04f9f), however that goes more for ***lazy loading*** implementation itself.

So, this is a typical `UI-Router` config block:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $injector) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'view_home.html',  // Actually SHOULD BE result of a XHR request ....
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        });
});
```

But what if I want to load such `templateUrl` when it's requested (`$stageChangeStart`) and it would be AJAX request based.

How should it be implemented? How are LARGE angular applications dealing with this?

Answer (score 5):

We should *(in this case)* use **`TemplateProvider`**. Small cite from doc:

#### [Templates](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#templates)

> **TemplateUrl**
> ... `templateUrl` can also be a function that returns a url. **It takes one preset parameter, `stateParams`, which is NOT injected.**
>
> **TemplateProvider**
> Or you can use a **template provider** function which **can be injected, has access to locals**, and must return template HTML, like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('contacts', {
  templateProvider: function ($timeout, $stateParams) {
    return $timeout(function () {
      return '<h1>' + $stateParams.contactId + '</h1>'
    }, 100);
  }
})
```

And there is even more.

We can use cooperation with really powerful

#### [`$templateRequest`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateRequest)

In this Q & A *([Angular UI-Router dynamic routing based on slug from API Ajax Call. Load view based on slug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30409740/1679310))* we can see so simple `templateProvider` defintion

```
.state('hybrid', {
    // /john-smith
    url: '/:slug',
    templateProvider: ['type', '$templateRequest',
      function(type, templateRequest) 
      {
        var tplName = "tpl.partial-" + type + ".html";
        return templateRequest(tplName);
      }
    ],
```

and the result is also chached...

There are some other links to similar Q & A, including working examples

- [Angular UI Router: decide child state template on the basis of parent resolved object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25289135/1679310)
- [Angular and UI-Router, how to set a dynamic templateUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26868796/1679310)

Comment: How do you access `$timeout` in the config phase, when `$stateProvider`  is configured?? `$timeout` is being configured then too and is not available.