# Using $http or $timeout with $stateProvider in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I come here from this question [Is it possible to load a template via AJAX request for UI-Router in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32794373/is-it-possible-to-load-a-template-via-ajax-request-for-ui-router-in-angular)

I wish to load a template for a given `state` using `$http`.

[ui.router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) docs shows examples where both `$timeout` and `$http` are used within `$stateProvider` config, e.g.

> Or you can use a template provider function which can be injected, has
>   access to locals, and must return template HTML, like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('contacts', {   templateProvider: function
 ($timeout, $stateParams) {
   return $timeout(function () {
    return '<h1>' + $stateParams.contactId + '</h1>'
   }, 100);   
 } 
})
```

However, as I understand it, `$stateProvider` has to be configured during `module.config` phase, and `$timeout` is not available then. I cannot find any example which shows how to access `$timeout` (or `$http`) for `$stateProvider` exactly per the example provided by the [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki).

Is there a way to access either `$timeout` or `$http` as defined in the docs? Do I configure state at another point? Is there an alternative way to do this which I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `templateProvider` function itself is injected with the dependencies using injector service, and it has nothing to do with the config phase.

So you should be able to use `$http` simply by injecting it in the function. If you see the example, `$timeout` or `$stateParams` are also not available at the config phase, but they work fine in the `templateProvider` function.

For example, the below snippet returns the content of HTTPBin:

```
templateProvider: function($http) {
  return $http.get('https://httpbin.org/get')
    .then(function(response) {
      return JSON.stringify(response.data);
    });
  }
```

For more details, refer to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yh1q2xt2/1/).

Comment: Ah! Good point. I was trying to inject `timeout` into the config. No wonder. I shall try it without and if it works tick your answer and give +1. Thank you.

Comment: @dewd -- please see my updated answer for more details.