# Angular Route: Define templateUrl based on rootScope condition

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, angular-ui-router, conditional-statements, rootscope

I am trying to dynamically change the `templateUrl` in the route. The problem is that in my function, the `$rootScope` with its parameter is not available.

Does someone has an idea to solve that?

```
angular.module('name').config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('tickets', {
    url: "/tickets",
    templateUrl: checkPartnerType,
    controller: 'TicketListController'
  })
 });

function checkPartnerType($rootScope){ 

    if( $rootScope.user.partner.type == 'NAT'){   
        return "core/partials/b2c-ticket-list.html"; 
    }else{
        return "core/partials/b2b-ticket-list.html"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try injecting $rootScope into the config function next to routeprovider but not sure if that will work. Honestly this is something that should be solved using state resolves and/or url params

Answer (score 0):

As documented here

#### [$stateProvider](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider)

The setting **`templateUrl`**:

> html template as a string or a function that returns an html template
>   as a string which should be used by the uiView directives. This
>   property takes precedence over templateUrl.
>
> **If template is a function, it will be called with the following
>   parameters:**
>
> - `{array.<object>}` - **state parameters** extracted from the current $location.path()
>     by applying the current state

So, the only param could be state params. But we have another option - **`templateProvider`**:

> Provider function that returns HTML content string.
>
> ```
> templateProvider:
>   function(MyTemplateService, params) {
>     return MyTemplateService.getTemplate(params.pageId);
>   }
> ```

With **`templateProvider`**, we can use all IoC power, and ask for any service to be injected. Check these:

- [Trying to Dynamically set a templateUrl in controller based on constant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27774287/1679310)
- [Angular ui.router reload parent templateProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29785692/1679310)