# Dynamic template Angular UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-ui-router, state

I'm trying to load a navbar according to the user.

To do this, I need to set a dynamic template, but I can't see my `$rootScope`

```
$stateProvider
    /*Login*/
    .state('login', {
        url: '/',
        data: {pageTitle: 'Inicio de sesión.'},
        resolve: {},
        views: {
            'navbar': {
                templateUrl: null,
                controller: null
            },
            'body': {
                templateUrl: "views/login.html",
                controller: 'LoginController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        data: {pageTitle: 'Home.'},
        views: {
            'navbar': {
                templateUrl: "views/navbar.html", //here dynamic template
                controller: null
            },
            'body': {
                templateUrl: "views/inicio.html",
                controller: null
            }
        }
    })
    .state('perfil', {
        url: '/perfil',
        data: {pageTitle: 'Perfil de usuario.'},
        views: {
            'navbar': {
                templateUrl: function (sessionProvider) {
                    var sessionFactory = sessionProvider.path();
                    return sessionFactory;
                }, // this return a tring, but don't load anything
                controller: null
            },
            'body': {
                templateUrl: "views/usuario/perfil.html",
                controller: 'UsuarioController'
            }
        }
    });
```

i've tried use a service to load the data, but it didnt work, also tried to load it from the localStorageService, but don't display anything.

is there a single way to load it ?

Comment: Did you tried ng-include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are features for this, like `templateUrl` and `templateProvider`. See all details here:

#### [Trying to Dynamically set a templateUrl in controller based on constant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27774287/1679310)

E.g. this could be an example of `templateProvider` used isntead of the *'templateUrl'* static path

```
templateProvider: function(CONFIG, $templateRequest) {
    console.log('in templateUrl ' + CONFIG.codeCampType);

    var templateName = 'index5templateB.html';

    if (CONFIG.codeCampType === "svcc") {
         templateName = 'index5templateA.html';
    } 

    return $templateRequest(templateName);
},
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what i was looking!

Comment: Great to see that, Enjoy mighty UI-Router ;)