# AngularJs- UI-router parent layout by child layout

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I am using angular js for creating spa(single page application) app.But i am facing issue while updating base layout by child layout.

Here is my app structure :: 
[image]

Anyone help me to design my app.

1).how to switch layout 1 to layout 2.

2).After loading layout 1 how to render it's child pages.

Comment: Read the ui router documentation, especially the section about named views, multiple views and child views it's fairly simple but you didn't tried it yet

Comment: Here  is how to use [layout with UI-Router](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25667660/1679310) and here how to make the [layout template dynamic](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27774287/1679310) ...

Comment: As written above, you should first read the great tutorials, and the post a question for a specific scenario/issue you're having with your project (supported by the code you're having trouble with), currently it's way to broad to answer

Comment: Appreciate your quick reply.But my question is how we can jump to layout1->page3 to layout2-page4 with spa. layout1 and layout 2 are two different templates.

Comment: @Niks It doesn't seem that you have actually **READ** the tutorials, because it's written there - black on white (but with pixels because it's computer), how to do it - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [AngularJS ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) with [$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider). Hope this can help

```
var Hero = angular.module('heroApp', ['ngRoute']);
Hero.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/photos', {
            templateUrl: '/photos.html',
            controller: 'photosCtrl'
        }).
        when('/users', {
            templateUrl: '/users.html',
            controller: 'usersCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    }]);
```

And URL to access the route beginning with `#` like this: http://localhost/#photos

Comment: But the OP is asking about [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) which is 100 times better than the basic angularjs routing service, and you can use `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` to tell angularjs to use the HTML5 routing when available