# requirejs with angular - not resolving controller dependency with nested route

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, requirejs, angular-ui-router

The `RequireJS` is not resolving dependency properly when the routes is of multiple levels as in `http://www.example.com/profile/view`. If I just have `http://www.example.com/view`, the controller dependency is resolved properly.

My bootstrap.js

```
require.config({
    baseUrl : 'res/js',
    paths: {
        routeResolve: 'routeResolve',
        'domReady': 'lib/domReady',
        angular: 'lib/angular',
        angularRoute: 'lib/angular-route',
        angularResource: 'lib/angular-resource',
        angularSanitize: 'lib/angular-sanitize',
        cssPath : '../css'
    },
    map: {
      '*': {
        css: 'lib/require-css/css.min'
      }
    },
    shim: {
        'angular': {'exports': 'angular'},
        'angularRoute': {deps : ['angular']},
        'angularResource': {deps : ['angular']},
        'angularSanitize': {deps : ['angular']}
    },
    priority: ['angular']
});
```

Folder structure:

```
-rootdir
    - public
          - res
              - js
              - css
```

When I use this route `http://www.example.com/profile/view`, all the dependency modules are resolved with base url as `http://www.example.com/profile/res/js/controller.js`, which does not exist in this path `http://www.example.com/profile`.

If I change the route to `http://www.example.com/view` (just one level), dependencies are resolved with this base url `http://www.example.com/res/js/controller.js`

There should be a configuration issue which I am missing, but I could not find a solution for this.

Comment: Minor note: `priority` is a RequireJS 1.x option which was removed in the 2.x series whereas `shim` is an option that was introduced in the 2.x series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created [working plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nl1W7AQW8776RIItuqph?p=info). It is based on the answer to [angular-ui-router with requirejs, lazy loading of controller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27754025/1679310). I would exepct that the issue will be related to HTML setting **`<base href...`**

There is an example of the state, which in **`resolve`** loads lazily controller via requireJS:

```
$stateProvider
  .state("first", {
    url: "/firstr",
    template: "<div>The message from ctrl: {{message}}</div>",
    controller: "FirstCtrl",
    resolve: {
      loadOtherCtrl: ["$q", function($q) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        require(["FirstCtrl"], function() { deferred.resolve(); });
        return deferred.promise;
      }],
    },
  });
```

There is the main.js for that example:

```
var cfg = {

    baseUrl: "res/js/",

    // alias libraries paths
    paths: { 

        // here we define path to NAMES
        // to make controllers and their lazy-file-names independent

        "TopMenuCtrl": "Controller_TopMenu", 
        "ContentCtrl": "Controller_Content", 
        "OtherCtrl"  : "Controller_Other",  
        "FirstCtrl"  : "Controller_First",
        "app"  : "../../app",  
    }, 

    deps: ['app'] 
} 

require.config(cfg);
```

The most important think here, because of the:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true});
```

is the setting of the **`base`** in the index.html:

```
<script>
  var urlBase = document.location.pathname;
  document.write('<base href="'+ urlBase +'" />')
</script>
```

Because I need here to be sure that this will work in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nl1W7AQW8776RIItuqph?p=info) I do generate that dynamically, but in your case it could be just `<base href="/" />` or some other setting, which will "teach" all the web where to search for resources

Check it [here in action](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nl1W7AQW8776RIItuqph?p=info). Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27754025/1679310)

Comment: Thanks for spending time on this. Checked out your code and found that adding base tag with just '/' fixed this. I tried this with full site url, which did not work. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Great to see that, enjoy mighty ui-router :)