# Dynamic controller isn't being initiated

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Following this thread [AngularJS UI router named views lazy loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30111594/angularjs-ui-router-named-views-lazy-loading), I wanting to have numerous tabs, with each one assigned it's own template and controller, like so:

```
angular.module('ppApp').config(function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
    .state('portfolio.patent', {
        url: '/:patentId',
        controller: 'mainItemCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'app/templates/patent/main.main-item.tpl.htm'
    }
})

angular.module('ppApp').controller('maintItemCtrl', function(){
    var vm = this;
    vm.leftTabs = {
        'tab1': {
            template: 'app/templates/child.sibling1.tpl.htm',
            controller: 'siblingOneCtrl'
        },
        'tab2': {
            template: 'app/templates/child.sibling2.tpl.htm',
            controller: 'siblingTwoCtrl'
        }
    }

});


<uib-tabset active="active">
    <uib-tab ng-repeat="(tabName,tab) in $ctrl.leftTabs" heading="{{tabName}}">
        <div template={{tab.template}} controller="{{tab.controller}}">Loading {{tabName}} ...</div>
    </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

I have the controllers set up for the sibling controllers and **they have worked** up until attempting to dynamically loading them into tabs. The template is loading into the view, though the controllers aren't being invoked. If I check the source code the controller directives have both sibling controllers as values.

**Question**

Why are my controllers not being initiated?

Comment: Are there any errors? How do you know that the controllers are not being initialized?

Comment: Using `console.log`

Answer (score 1):

I have never tried this, but it's likely because interpolation of expressions happens too late to access and influence the life-cycle phases where controller construction and initialisation occur.

At least, in directive controllers, interpolation occurs after `$postLink`, which means that by this point, all children have been linked, and its far too late in the parent's life-cycle to declare and instantiate new child controllers.

EDIT:
[this is confirmed by the docs:](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

> Controller constructor function. The controller is instantiated before the pre-linking phase and can be accessed by other directives (see require attribute).